# URL Redirection, with target location stored in a variable

Tags: php, html, http-headers

I have a problem redirecting my page, when the target location is stored in a variable.

This code works:

```php
header('location:demo.php');
```

But this code doesn't work:

```php
$ss='demo.php';
header('location:$ss');
```

Why? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use double quotes here.
PHP does only parse text inside double quotes.

If you type for example

```
echo '$text\n';
```

It does not output the variables content, nor the newline. Corect would be:

```
echo "$test\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a variable to re-direct try this...

```
<?php 

$var = 'location:';
$var .= 'demo.php';

header ($var);

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use double quotes around location:$ss.

Answer (score 1):

In PHP **variables** do **not** **expand** within single quotes. Just **use** **double quotes** instead and it will work:

```
<?php

    $ss='demo.php';
    header("location:$ss");

?>
```